# If $f(x)$ denotes a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $f(k) =\dfrac1k$ for $k = 1,2,3,\ldots,(n+1)$, determine $f(n + 2)$.

Tags: polynomials

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $$f(k) =\dfrac1k$$ for $k = 1,2,3,\ldots,(n+1)$.  Determine $f(n + 2)$.

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636919/suppose-that-px-is-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-such-that-pk-dfrackk1%20but%20I%20am%20unable%20to%20relate%20the%20two). How do I solve such type of problems in general?

Comment: $P(k)=k/(k+1)$ for an interesting range of numbers if and only if $1-P(k)=1/(k+1)$ for that same range. Looks like you may be looking for $f(x)=1-P(x-1)$ where $P(x)$ the polynomial that popped out in the linked question. Adjust $n$ by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Note that we have $kf(k) = 1$ for $k = 1,\ldots,n+1$, and clearly $0f(0) = 0$. So now we know $n+2$ values of the $(n+1)$-degree polynomial $xf(x)$.

As for the general bit, it's difficult to say. You should try to make everything into polynomials as nicely as possible, because polynomials are a lot easier to work with than rational functions. Case in point: I can't tell much about $f(x)$ just from knowing the solutions of $f(x) = \frac1x$, but I *can* tell a lot about $xf(x)$ from knowing the solutions to $xf(x) = 1$.

It won't always work, though, and the most important thing, as with problem solving in general, is to just *try things* and not give up when your first attempt fails. Remember that when you read a solution that someone else has written to a problem like this, you only see the attempts that succeeded. Behind each successful solution are either a lot of failed attempts at solving the problem, or the experience needed to write a solution more or less on the first attempt, built up through a lot of trial and error on other, similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x):=x\,f(x)$ like Arthur suggests.  Then, $g$ is of degree $n+1$.  Hence, from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2289642/represent-n-by-binomial-coefficients/2289660#2289660), we have 
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n+2}\,(-1)^r\,\binom{n+2}{r}\,g(x+r)\equiv 0\,.$$
In particular,
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n+2}\,(-1)^r\,\binom{n+2}{r}\,g(r)=0\,.$$
As $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=g(2)=\ldots=g(n+1)=1$, we conclude that
$$\begin{align}g(n+2)&=(-1)^{n+1}\,\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}\,(-1)^{r}\,\binom{n+2}{r}
\\&=(-1)^{n+1}\,\left((1-1)^{n+2}-1-(-1)^{n+2}\right)=(-1)^{n}+1\,.\end{align}$$
Consequently,
$$f(n+2)=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{n+2}\,.$$